# operator+ doesn't work when both parameters need to be promoted

Tags: c++, operators, promotions

I have a class named 'Card' and a class named 'CardDeck', with the following promotion defined in 'CardDeck.h':

```
CardDeck(Card card){cards.push_back(card);}
```

CardDeck has a friend operator+:

```
friend CardDeck operator+(const CardDeck, const CardDeck);
```

which works just fine for:

```
CardDeck+CardDeck
CardDeck+Card
Card+CardDeck
```

but it won't work for Card+Card. I get:

```
"no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Card' and 'Card')"
```

Why aren't the Cards being promoted to CardDecks in that case?
I also tried overriding operator+ with:

```
friend CardDeck operator+(const Card, const Card);
```

but that doesn't work either.
any hint why?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you pass `const CardDeck&`, i.e. const references to `operator +`.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem here. Could you show us last operator definition?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know you want a `CardDeck` from 2 `Deck`s? What if there are more classes that also expose constructors for `Card`? This would be ambigious.

Comment: What would `friend CardDeck operator+(const Card, const Card)` do and on what object? Would you create a `CardDeck` object that added the 2 `Card`'s to it and returned that, i.e. `Card c1,c2; CardDeck cd = c1+c2`?

Comment: This is a variation of the same theme: `std::string s = "a" + "b";` and expecting `+` to do a concatenation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, no, it is not! There is no overload of operator+ for string literals defined.

Comment: The code is compilable (see answer by @BlackMoses). I believe, there is something else at play.

Comment: @SergeyA It isn't compilable here:  http://ideone.com/UnuCEu

Comment: @SergeyA *no, it is not! There is no overload of operator+ for string literals defined* -- That's my point.  There is no operator "+" for two string literals even though each can be implicitly converted to `std::string`, just like there there is no operator+ for two `Card` objects even though there is a conversion to a `CardDeck`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Did you try to implement the function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, this is because you never defined operator+. Here is the version which works:
http://ideone.com/lkr5ME

Comment: @BlackMoses No, just trying to duplicate the OP's situation.  .

Comment: Important detail: is `operator+` declared outside the class, or is its only declaration a definition with the `friend` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out @PaulMcKenzie had the answer (unfortunatly I can't mark his comment as a solution):
The operator was defined inside the class, so it wasn't available for 'Card'. For some reason I thought that implemanting it in the source file will be enough for it to be known by outsiders, but that's obviously not true as outsiders don't know anything about the source file.
the code provided by Paul shows the solution:

http://ideone.com/lkr5ME

Thanks Paul!

```
a
```

Answer (score 3):

Works for me though!

```
class A
{
    public:
    A() {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A sth) {}
};

B operator+(const B x, const B y)
{
    return B(A());
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A x;
    B y(x);
    y + y;
    x + y;
    y + x;
    x + x;
    return 0;
}
```

No errors expect unused parameters and expressions.

Comment: @shayelk what line do you mean?

Comment: sorry, the comment was sent by mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking Black Moses has it partially right.  It looks like you're declaring the implementation of the operator inside the class with the friend keyword.  That creates the compilation error you're talking about, i.e. it appears you're doing the following:

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(A sth) { ... }

    friend int operator+(const B x, const B Y)
    {
        return 0;
    }

};
```

If you use what Black Moses did in his example, and add the following to your class:

```
friend int operator+(const B x, const B y);
```

then the compilation error goes away.  To summarize: declare the operator a friend function inside your class definition, and then declare the implementation outside the class, like so:

```
int operator+(const B x, const B y)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: operator+ is defined as a friend in the class, and is implemented in the source file, just as you suggest. still doesn't work...
the weird thig is that I can't even get an overloaded version which takes two cards to work.